# How to prevent <label> events from triggering associated element?

Tags: html, css

When a `<label>` is hovered upon, the first element's hover effect is triggered (in this case, the first `<button>` element)

How to prevent this?

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.10);
}
```

```html
<label>
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <button>Button 3</button>
    </label>
```

Comment: “*Permitted content: ...No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed.*” There should be only one labelable element within a [`<label>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Technical_summary), and ideally not including interactive elements such as `<button>` elements.

Comment: And what would happen if I use non-permitted content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it a bogus `for` attribute:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.10);
}
```

```html
<label for="foo">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <button>Button 3</button>
    </label>
```

Comment: @VardanBetikyan Adding a non-existent for attribute value disassociates the label to any specific input.